# Difference between virtual and non virtual function for child class

Tags: c++, overriding

Let my `parent` class be;

```
class parent {  
    virtual void printx () { cout<< "parent" ; }  
}
```

Case 1:

```
class child : public parent {  
     virtual void printx() { cout<< " child" ; }  
}
```

Case 2:

```
class child : public parent { 
    void printx() { cout<< " child" ; }  
}
```

Is there any difference if I omit `virtual` in the `child` class for the function `printx` in case 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided the function signatures are the same, the `child` class is not required to add the `virtual` to the method, the compiler will take care of this for you. **If a function is declared virtual in a parent class, the child's overridden methods are also virtual.**

If C++11 is available, consider adding the [`override` specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) to the overridden method in the child class;

```
class child : public parent { 
    void printx() override { cout<< " child" ; }  
}
```

With the `override`, the compiler will check to make sure that this method does indeed override a virtual method in the base class. If it does not, the compiler will generate an error for you. For example; as in the original posting, it will pick up the spelling difference between `printx` and `pritnx`.

Comment: +1 Importantly... this will draw attention to the fact that `printx` and `pritnx` differ....

Answer (score 3):

Both are same. If a function is declared as virtual in base class then it would be virtual in all derived classes whether you explicitly mention it or not.